# Searching for ressource recommendations (books,papers) to validate the results of a Topic Model (LDA)?

Tags: python, topic-model, lda

Hi I am building a Topic Model Process with Python.
To do this I am using the LDA.

However I am having trouble to determine the ideal amount of topics.

Currently I am using the CoherenceModel Module of the gensim libary to evaluate my results. Are there better/ more efficient ways to this?

Are there any good books or papers that tackle this topic?

If anyone here has experience with Topic Modelling, how do you evaluate, validate and interpret the results of the LDA?

Any help is welcome.